# RADIUS authentication

Tags: cisco, authentication, radius

I am configuring RADIUS authentication on my switches but it does not work and I don't know why.

My configuration is pretty straightforward :

```
aaa new-model
aaa group server radius RADIUS-ACTIF
  server x.x.x.x auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
  server y.y.y.y auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
  ip radius source-interface Vlan10
  deadtime 1
aaa authentication attempts login 5
aaa authentication password-prompt Secured-Password:
aaa authentication username-prompt Secured-Username:
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authentication login RADIUS-ACTIF group RADIUS-ACTIF local
aaa authentication enable default enable
aaa authorization exec default group RADIUS-ACTIF local
aaa session-id common

line vty 0 4
    login authentication RADIUS-ACTIF
```

The thing is : I can't see anything happening on the "Failed Attempts" on my ACS Server. There are no logs of my attempts at authentication.

ACS server is reachable via ping from my switches.
I have tried to test the RADIUS access with the **test** command : I get the **User rejected** feedback after less than 2/3 seconds, so I am thinking that I can access the RADIUS but I get blocked even before submitting my credentials. It's a very strange behavior.

Does anybody has an idea as to why this would happen?

I should also say that the exact same configuration is working on one switch (on a different IP plan though.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the router has client on the ACS? Did you set the key on the router?

Comment: There is no key exchange between router & ACS (unlike if I had used TACACS.) My router is a client on the RADIUS server though, with vlan 10 IP.

Comment: I'm referring to the pre-shared key.

Comment: Oh dear. I am such an idiot. I forgot to set the PSK. Thank you very much for pointing it out to me, I could have gone hours before realizing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my experience the two most common issues when dealing with AAA and Radius are:

- Misspelled/Absent pre-shared key on the RADIUS server or on the NAC (Radius client)
- The Radius server misses the configuration to allow requests from a client.

Doing troubleshooting with comments it turned out that the pre-shared key was missing on the router.

To add this just type:

```
(config)#radius-server host x.x.x.x auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key ***
```

or (to define a default key):

```
(config)#radius-server key ***
```

If you are interested in a more general method for troubleshooting refere here: [Troubleshooting RADIUS and TACACS+](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5989/prod_troubleshooting_guide_chapter09186a0080679eb2.html#wp36461)